# How to capture the clipboard changes from Lazarus?

Tags: winapi, clipboard, lazarus

How can I capture the changes made to the clipboard from a Lazarus program in windows. For example, to save a clipboard history to a file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in Lazarus as in any Windows development environment. You need to add yourself into the chain of clipboard viewers.

There are many articles on the web describing how to do it. For example:

- http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/clipboard_spy_2.htm
- http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3359891/C-Tip-Monitoring-Clipboard-Activity-in-C.htm
- http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have found this and managed to get it work, but forgot to save it and now struggling to figure how i managed to make it work:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode delphi}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  Clipbrd, StdCtrls, Windows, Messages;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FNextClipboardOwner: HWnd;   // handle to the next viewer
    // Here are the clipboard event handlers
    function WMChangeCBChain(wParam: WParam; lParam: LParam):LRESULT;
    function WMDrawClipboard(wParam: WParam; lParam: LParam):LRESULT;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}
var
  PrevWndProc:windows.WNDPROC;

function WndCallback(Ahwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WParam;
  lParam: LParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if uMsg = WM_CHANGECBCHAIN then begin
    Result := Form1.WMChangeCBChain(wParam, lParam);
    Exit;
  end 
  else if uMsg=WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD then begin
    Result := Form1.WMDrawClipboard(wParam, lParam);
    Exit;
  end;
  Result := CallWindowProc(PrevWndProc, Ahwnd, uMsg, WParam, LParam);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrevWndProc := Windows.WNDPROC(SetWindowLong(Self.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, PtrInt(@WndCallback)));
  FNextClipboardOwner := SetClipboardViewer(Self.Handle);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChangeClipboardChain(Handle, FNextClipboardOwner);
end;

function TForm1.WMChangeCBChain(wParam: WParam; lParam: LParam): LRESULT;
var
  Remove, Next: THandle;
begin
  Remove := WParam;
  Next := LParam;
  if FNextClipboardOwner = Remove then FNextClipboardOwner := Next
    else if FNextClipboardOwner <> 0 then
      SendMessage(FNextClipboardOwner, WM_ChangeCBChain, Remove, Next)
end;

function TForm1.WMDrawClipboard(wParam: WParam; lParam: LParam): LRESULT;
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) Then Begin
    ShowMessage(Clipboard.AsText);
  end;
  SendMessage(FNextClipboardOwner, WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD, 0, 0);   // VERY IMPORTANT
  Result := 0;
end;

end.
```

Above code is from http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Clipboard and in theory it should work. It compiles and runs but no window pops up when the clipboard content changes. Maybe someone else here have got better eyes to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

On Vista and later, you should be using AddClipboardFormatListener() instead of SetClipboardViewer().
This working example originally posted on Lazarus Forums by ASerge and Remy: [Not reacting to clipboard change - windows](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,15488.msg225927.html#msg225927)

```
unit ClipboardListener;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes;

type
  { TClipboardListener }

  TClipboardListener = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FOnClipboardChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FWnd: HWND;
    class function GetSupported: Boolean; static;
    procedure WindowProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnClipboardChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnClipboardChange
      write FOnClipboardChange;
    class property Supported: Boolean read GetSupported;
  end;

implementation

uses SysUtils, LCLIntf;

var
  AddClipboardFormatListener: function(Wnd: HWND): BOOL; stdcall;
  RemoveClipboardFormatListener: function(Wnd: HWND): BOOL; stdcall;

procedure InitClipboardFormatListener;
var
  HUser32: HMODULE;
begin
  HUser32 := GetModuleHandle(user32);
  Pointer(AddClipboardFormatListener) :=
    GetProcAddress(HUser32, 'AddClipboardFormatListener');
  Pointer(RemoveClipboardFormatListener) :=
    GetProcAddress(HUser32, 'RemoveClipboardFormatListener');
end;

{ TClipboardListener }

constructor TClipboardListener.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  if GetSupported then
  begin
    FWnd := LCLIntf.AllocateHWnd(@WindowProc);
    if not AddClipboardFormatListener(FWnd) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;

destructor TClipboardListener.Destroy;
begin
  if FWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    RemoveClipboardFormatListener(FWnd);
    LCLIntf.DeallocateHWnd(FWnd);
  end;
  inherited;
end;

class function TClipboardListener.GetSupported: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Assigned(AddClipboardFormatListener) and
    Assigned(RemoveClipboardFormatListener);
end;

procedure TClipboardListener.WindowProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if (Msg.msg = WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE) and Assigned(FOnClipboardChange) then
  begin
    Msg.Result := 0;
    FOnClipboardChange(Self);
  end;
end;

initialization
  InitClipboardFormatListener;
end.
```

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  ClipboardListener, Classes, Forms, StdCtrls;

type
  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FListener: TClipboardListener;
    procedure ClipboardChanged(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.ClipboardChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Append(timetostr(Now)+' ['+Clipboard.AsText+']')   
// Memo1.Lines.Append('Clipboard changed');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FListener := TClipboardListener.Create;
  FListener.OnClipboardChange := @ClipboardChanged;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FListener.Free;
end;

end.
```